# How can I keep a PostgreSQL query running after lient (PGAdmin) is disconnected?

Tags: postgresql, client, pgadmin, dbeaver

I am running long queries on managed PostgreSQL server instances. Since I have no access to the underlying OS I need to use a client (DBeaver or PGAdmin etc) on my local laptop to run queries. I's like to avoid my queries from stopping when I have an internet outage and also avoid having to leave my laptop on for hours just to maintain a connection.

With MS SQl Server, I used SQLAgent to run the queries directly on the server and so could shut down my laptop and the queries would carry on without issue.

Is there a way to trigger a query to run independently from the client admin software that triggered it?

Thanks

Comment: And then you come back later, log on again, and check the results?  Or what?

Comment: With RDS, you can run a EC2 nano instance as a jump box.  ssh to that, run 'screen', and then psql into the RDS within the screen session.  You should be to follow the same principle with DBeaver or pgAdmin running over xterm or RDS, though I've never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible, unless you have a third-party extension like `pg_timetable` or `pg_cron` installed.

Answer (score 0):

Observed on Windows 11 and pgAdmin 4 : if you kill the pgAdmin process from the Task Manager, then query execution is preserved. That what you can check by re-open pgAdmin.